# Can I split an array of this format to this?

Tags: php

How can I do the below change in PHP?

Input:

```
[hiddenAllPrefered] => Array
(
    [0] => 14477,14478,14479,14485,14486,14487
)
```

Output should be like this:

```
[hiddenAllPrefered] => Array
(
    [0] => 14477,14478,14479
    [1] => 14485,14486,14487
)
```

Comment: What's the splitting rule? By number? Read about PHP functions [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php), [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). Combining them you can get what you need.

Comment: Rule: split by first 3 comma seperated values

Comment: As I said, the above-mentioned PHP functions can do the job. Just try them.

Comment: Is this an array inside another array?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
$input = array('14477,14478,14479,14485,14486,14487');

$output = array_map(
    function (array $a){
        return implode(',', $a);
    },
    array_chunk(
        explode(',', $input[0]),
        3
    )
);
```

Read it from inside out:

- `explode()` splits the string `$input[0]` using comma (`,`) as delimiter and returns an array;
- `array_chunk()` splits the array into chunks of size `3`; it returns an array of arrays, each inner array contains `3` elements (apart from the last one that can contain less);
- `array_map()` applies the function it receives as its first argument to each value of the array it gets as its second argument (the array of arrays returned by `array_chunk()`); it returns an array whose values are the values returned by the function;
- the [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) passed to `array_map()` gets an array (of size `3` or less) and uses `implode()` to join its elements into a string, using comma (`,`) to separate the values and returns the string;
- `array_map()` puts together all the values returned by the anonymous function (one for each chunk of `3` elements of the array) into a new array it returns.

The output (`print_r($output)`) looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 14477,14478,14479
    [1] => 14485,14486,14487
)
```

Comment: Thanks Worked Great.

Answer (score 0):

try this as a boilerplate

```
function chunker($arr, $l) { 
  return array_chunk($arr, $l); 
}
print_r(chunker($hap, 3));
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14477
            [1] => 14478
            [2] => 14479
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14485
            [1] => 14486
            [2] => 14487
        )

)
*/
```

**UPDATE**

```
php > $h = [ "14477,14478,14479,14485,14486,14487" ];
php > $hap = explode(",", $h[0]);
php > print_r($hap);
Array
(
    [0] => 14477
    [1] => 14478
    [2] => 14479
    [3] => 14485
    [4] => 14486
    [5] => 14487
)
php > print_r(chunker($hap, 3));
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14477
            [1] => 14478
            [2] => 14479
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14485
            [1] => 14486
            [2] => 14487
        )

)
php >
```

Comment: Getting Output as follows:Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15087,15088,15089,15095,15096,15097
        )

)

Comment: I said you to use it as a boilerplate, what you should actually do is.. ok i am updating answer -))